# How can I sum integers line by line until a new line and then start again?

Tags: python, integer, sum

I have a file like this:

```
1
2
3

5
0

5
2
3
```

What I want to do is to sum the integers until the newline and then start to sum again, so the result would be:

```
6

5

10
```

What I have so far is:

```
import sys

def readText(filename):
    sum = 0

    data = open(filename,'r')

    for line in data.readlines():
        if (line[0] != '\n'):
            sum+=int(line)
        else:
            sum = 0
            continue

    print sum

if len(sys.argv) == 2:
    lines = readText(sys.argv[1])
else:
    print("script.py inputfile")
```

But I get only the sum of the last "group" of integers, in this example 10. I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

move `print (sum)` before the the `sum = 0` and you'll be fine

Note that the line `sum = 0` in the loop makes you sum from the start (and you "forget" all previous numbers...)

*print sum is for python 2 and I use 3, hence the print (sum) in the print method*

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you!